# Twitter Bootstrap Thumbnail. Make Caption Inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Look At [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/779/)

The Code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Aplikasi Intranet</legend>
                <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1">
            <a style="margin-bottom:0;">
            <center>
                <img width="64" height="56" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:0;"/>
            <b>Mail</b>
            </center>
                </a>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1">
            <a style="margin-bottom:0;">
            <center>
                <img width="64" height="56" src="http://placehold.it/200x150" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:0;"/>
            <b>Mail Bla Bla Bla</b>
            </center>
                </a>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1">
            <a style="margin-bottom:0;">
            <center>
                <img width="64" height="56" src="http://placehold.it/200x165" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:0;"/>
            <b>Mail Mail Bla Bla Bla</b>
            </center>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

With various image height, How to make the caption stay on the same line? (The Spacing responsively refer to highest image)

Expected Layout:

[image: Expected Caption Position]

Comment: The fiddle has nothing to do with your expected layout...

Comment: Oh I'm Sorry. I have updated the link.

Comment: You're aware that bootstrap's thumbnail is a class not a solution. That is if your images, text, headline, all and everything inside the .thumbnail are not exactly the same height/character count the result is : http://jsbin.com/OvobotIg/1/. To avoid the non-clearing have to wrap each section that adds up to 12 in a row or use some other means of clearing, but even then the results are not so hot. There's no solution for equal heights masonry type layouts in Boostrap without adding them. Here's something I did with masonry/isotope: http://jsbin.com/OvobotIg/2/.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your `img` in a container, and set a height on this container :

```
<a style="margin-bottom:0;">
    <center>
        <div class="img_container">
            <img width="64" height="56" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:0;"/>
        </div>
        <b>Mail</b>
    </center>
</a>
```

```
.img_container {
    height: 56px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/52VtD/781/)

### EDIT :

To get an alignment with dynamic height, you may rearrange your HTML structure :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1">
        <a href="#"><center>
            <img width="64" height="56" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:0;"/>
        </center></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1">
        <a href="#"><center>
            <img width="64" height="56" src="http://placehold.it/200x150" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:0;"/>
        </center></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1">
        <a href="#"><center>
            <img width="64" height="56" src="http://placehold.it/200x165" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:0;"/>
        </center></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1">
        <a href="#"><center>
            <b>Mail</b>
        </center></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1">
        <a href="#"><center>
            <b>Mail Bla Bla Bla</b>
        </center></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1">
        <a href="#"><center>
            <b>Mail Mail Bla Bla Bla</b>
        </center></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/52VtD/799/)

Comment: Could the `height` size dynamically refer to highest image?

Comment: I don't think so, as `<img>` aren't siblings. But you could break your links in 2 parts : one for the picture, and on for the text (then you would be able to auto align pictures, see my edit)